# data load scripts in Ruby - Make ETL in ruby scripts more dynamic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, etl, rails-postgresql

I have written a bunch of data loading commandline ruby scripts. Most of the scripts extract data from one database table and load the data to another database. For the most part, there is a one-to-one table mapping. `Extract columns a,b,c from table A and load into column d,e,f in table B.` Except the column names are different in the source than the target. I use SQL strings in ruby to pull the data and load to the target tables. The SQL could have some fancy logic such as aggregation before loading to the target.

Is there a way I can make this more dynamic? Turn this into a data loading utility program. Maybe have an updatable configuration file that has  the source and target database tables and the query for the extraction and load. Or instead of a configuration file, pass the arguments through the command line. Does anyone have any clever ideas about how to do something like this?

Comment: You will need some mapping data that your Ruby program uses to map Database1 Table Column  to Database2 Table Column.  Also take a look a some open source ETL tools, maybe they can help you speed up doing ETL. Try Talend, Pentaho, and Clover ETL all have community editions that are free to use.

Comment: i do this with yaml configurationfiles and activerecord to ease the sql part, if you publish a short code example of the kind of loading you do we could do a more to the point suggesion